# Wp7 create path element from code and set Data element

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geometry

I have this path in xaml:

```
<Path Data="M 16,12 16,0 0,12" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
```

I want to generate it dynamically through code. The problem is that I couldnt figure out how to set the Data element. I've read something about Geometry.Parse() then it turned out that it can be used only in WPF projects not WP7.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

To specify the path in code you'd need to create a `Geometry` object and set that as the value of the `Data` property.
e.g.:

```
myPath.Data = new EllipseGeometry 
                  {
                      Centre = new Point(50, 50),
                      RadiusX = 25,
                      RadiusY = 25
                  };
```

It is not possible to use the abbreviated syntax (e.g. `"M 16,12 16,0 0,12"`) from code behind. This is only supported by the XAML parser.

See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.105).aspx